# Multi sub-attributes for manage types of colors with only one selection available

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product

I need some help for setting up a configurable products with this features.

Let's say we are selling a cushion. We have two kind of tissues in different colors: cotton and acrylic.

Cotton is available in red and green. Acrylic id available in brown and white.
So we create two attributes, cotton and acrylic and add attribute values for colors.

Now we create the configurable product cushion01 with the proper attribute set (both cotton and acrylic attribute available).

The problem is in simple products association: I can create and associate a simple but I need to define both the two attributes. And this is NOT what we want: if a user chooses "acrylic white" he cannot choose "cotton red". We only want a single attribute to be selected from one of the two tissue dropdowns.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply create two products (one for cotton and one for acrylic) or use custom options if stock management is not important...

Comment: @Simon Two product was my first choice but it is a problem with Erp sync and other things.. What do you mean with "custom options"?

Comment: Create a simple product and use the "custom options" tab on the left-hand side to create the options. You may need to add some validation rules to fit your needs though (so that the customer can only select one option). And as said, there is no stock management in this case.

Comment: @Simon feel free to add this as an answer

Comment: @DavidManners here you go

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create two products (one for cotton and one for acrylic).

You may also be able to use custom options if stock management is not important. Therefore, create a simple product and use the "custom options" tab on the left-hand side to create the options. You may need to add some validation rules to fit your needs though (so that the customer can only select one option).

Another option may be to simply create a combined attribute like cotton/blue.